# Joomla css hide date create

Tags: css, joomla

I want to hide the date on this [page](http://www.syntexnia.gr/boutique/index.php?option=com_jkit&view=item&layout=gallery&id=27&Itemid=160&lang=en).

I tried to change it inside joomla but I couldn't. It's not an article but a JKit page and there is no such an option.

I used the "inspect element" feature to find the corresponding css file and line (bootstrap.css #554). When I change the element through the "inspect element" menu its working but when I open the css file and change it, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions how I can hide it?

Comment: override the component tpl file in your template, and remove the date section in that file

Comment: can you give more info or link of how I can do this?

Comment: Information on how to do this is available on docs.joomla.org, and the template manager will help you with getting started.

Answer (score 1):

```
p.meta {display: none;}
```

That ought to do it. Granted, any other metadata will also be hidden. You should add this to a **[custom CSS file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template)** and not modify core Joomla or extension files.

I find it hard to believe that jKit doesn't have a setting for that. (Update: I see that jKit is very new and lacks good documentation.) Also, a **[template override](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)** might be more to your liking.

Comment: I added a note saying that you shouldn't modify core files, and a link to more info on the right way to do it. I can't really say not knowing much about your site or template.

Comment: I have an existing custom.css with some working contents. I added it there but still doesn't work.

Comment: Increase specificity (`body p.meta {}`), or add `!important` (as a last resort). There's no other reason this wouldn't work.

Comment: I added the !important but still doesn't work...
`p.meta {display: none !important;}`

Comment: Does that statement show up in your page code? There's not much I can tell you without seeing it.

Comment: do you have time so you can look it? if yes send me email to angelos1707@gmail.com so I can give you details... thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Most Joomla components allow you to control things like this in the options for the items and also in the menu options when creating a menu link (or setting the global options to change the default behavior. If this component does not, make either an alternate layout or a template override (depending on whether you want to always change this or just on this one page).  If you go into the template manager, template view there is a system in place that will automatically create a copy of the layout and put it in the right location.  Just edit that to show what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I solved by editing the according .php file of the component.

I just removed the echo line of the date.

Nothing else worked.